# How to make a textField as firstResponder in Swift iOS - UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield, uitextview

In a ViewController and have an UITextView and UITextField.
I have selected a range of texts in a textView. So the textView has a cursor selection.

I have to apply some attributes to the selectedRange of text in the textView by entering some values using the TextField.

So, I need to enter the values for the selectedRange of text using the textField. When i tap the TextField, Its became the FirstResponder, but at the same time the selectedRange in the textView is nil. (The cursor selection disables)

But, I need to apply the values to the selectedRange of text in the textView and it is not recommended to store the selectedRange in a variable, then to apply the values to stored selectedRange of text.

Please help to attain this, i.e. To make the textField as a firstResponder without removing the selection made in the TextView.

Comment: Please review [ask]. It is not clear what you are trying to do or what is not working the way you want.

Comment: Now the question has been edited with clear understanding @[DonMag] (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6257435/donmag)

Comment: Can anyone, Help me to solve this problem ... Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is any way to "keep the selection highlight" when the text view is no longer active. Options could be: use attributed text and give the selection range a background color; get the frame of the selection highlight and draw it yourself; grab a snapshot of the text view and overlay it while editing the text field?